# How can I tell if my mongodb instance is running on WiredTiger or MMAPV1?

Tags: mongodb

I think the title itself is self explanatory. I need to know the engine which my mongo instance is running on. Preferably a script to execute or something

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: version `4.0`. I know it is wiredtiger by default. I want to know its still the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `serverStatus` command output has a property [serverStatus.storageEngine](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/command/serverStatus/#storageengine). *It is a document with data about the current storage engine*. The `name` property of this document tells the *current storage engine*.

The command can also be run with this method: `db.serverStatus()`

For example, `db.serverStatus().storageEngine`, returns:

```
{
        "name" : "wiredTiger",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : true,
        "oldestRequiredTimestampForCrashRecovery" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "supportsPendingDrops" : true,
        "dropPendingIdents" : NumberLong(0),
        "supportsSnapshotReadConcern" : true,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : true,
        "backupCursorOpen" : false
}
```

The output can have fewer fields with other versions of MongoDB (the above is from version 4.2.8).

Answer (score 0):

You can interrogate it with

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts().parsed.storage.engine
```

If you get an empty result, then it is the default `wiredTiger` (maybe on very old DB the default is different, check documentation)

I found another command:

```
db.serverStatus().storageEngine.name

db.getCollection(<collection>).stats()
```

Comment: `engine` property not found in `parsed.storage`. So I can assume its wiredTiger only right

Comment: This only works if you 1) also know the server version and 2) know what the default storage engine is for that version.